# How to distinguish AMP Form Success analytics event in case of multiple forms

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

My page contains two forms : Form1 and Form2

I want to track submission success and failure event for both of them separately.

`amp-form-submit` generates `FormId` through which I can distinguish but its not working in the case of the `amp-form-submit-success` and `amp-form-submit-error` . Any Idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug, can you please file an issue on [Github](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form#analytics-triggers) .